# In Atom IDE, find and replace < and > with &gt; and &lt; respectively in one go?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have tons of html pages where there are some parts I'll have to replace all the `<` and `>` signs with their HTML entity version, `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I'll manually select all the parts in the page and then let RegExp to find both these signs and replace them with one go. I had been experimenting with this for hours but no luck.

```
(<)[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s,",",=,-]+(>)
```

I have this which selects the whole line and when I do back-reference with $1 and $2, the whole line gets replaced.

What is:

```
<span class="avatar2-default bg-dark rounded-circle">
    <a href="">Hello</a>
    <input type="text">
</span>
```

What is needed (entities might mismatch, but that's kind of the intention):

```
&lt;span class="avatar2-default bg-dark rounded-circle"&t;
    &lt;a href=""&lt;Hello&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;input type="text"&gt;
&lt;/span&gt;
```

Comment: Curious what the use case is for needing to do this

Comment: I don't get why you need regex. Why can't you just do a search and replace in all folders to replace `<` with `&lt;`, and then another search and replace to replace `>` with `&gt;`?

Comment: @charlietfl There is this Javascript library named prism which does syntax highlighting on the web, like when we view them with browsers. If I put the code and tags as is, they will not be shown as browser will interpret them and show only the text inside the HTML tags as usual, not the code.

Comment: Pretty sure there are online tools that do the same. I have used them to do the exact thing for Google AdSense codes.

Comment: @Mr.Me Because I'll not replace all of them. There are for example 10 sections in a 1000 line page and will replace them in those sections only. And I have like 80 pages to do the same thing.

Comment: @CinCout By any chance, you remember the website name? I searched but came up with nothing which does exactly this.

Comment: Would be simple enough to this at run time

Comment: [This](https://convert.blogsupporter.com/) one for instance.

Comment: @charlietfl It's HTML, no server-side language involved. I just want to show HTML code as written in IDE with syntax highlighted. Highlighter libraries require those replaces.

Comment: JS runtime in live page is what I meant, before you invoke the prism library

Comment: @CinCout Nice resource but the problem is I'll not convert the whole page or code, different parts of the page. I ahve a bunch of pages and copying them one by one would cost me tonnes of time and labor. Regexp line of solution will be a timesaver.

Comment: You could use `(<)([a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s,",",=,-]+)(>)` as the regex, and replace it with `&lt;$2&gt;`, and that keeps the whole line from getting replaced. What are the conditions that decide when you want to replace the angled brackets and when you don't. We would need to know that to be able to create a regex that meets your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that there should be some libraries that might do so.

If not, this'd be rather complicated to be done with regular expressions, maybe it would be OK to try and test multiple regular expressions on specific tags, with some expressions that would look like:

```
(?i)<(\/?\b(?:span|a|input|div|i|b|s|u|br|li|ul|ol|small|img|body|html|head|h[1-6]|title|em)\b[^>]*)>
```

and our desired elements would go in this non-capturing group using logical ORs:

```
(?:span|...)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WrswFd/1/)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Vxdb3O/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Vxdb3O/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Edge Cases:

One problem would be on `[^>]*` part of the expression, which would fail in [such instances](https://regex101.com/r/4U5Dgb/1/)